# Install Device Unit Test Framework

Tags: unit-testing, compact-framework, device

I have Framework2.0 already installed in device, I have created a unit Test project for the smartDevice application, now to test this project I need to have Device Unit Test Framework installed in the machine.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545998.aspx

Here I want to know if Device Unit Test Framework is distributed independently. I tried to find it out but no luck. I am not fine with installing complete .net Compact Framework 3.5 just to run the unit test project because my application ( for which unit test project is created) is using .net framework 2.0 only.

Can any body tell me. If VS2005 provides Unit testing functionality of DEVICES.

Answer (score 1):

The Device Unit Test Framework also supports .NET Compact Framework 2.0, so you're fine there.

Please read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513875.aspx) article to see how to configure and run the unit tests on your device.

Comment: This is showing just, how to debug the code while unit testing the device.

Answer (score 1):

I do a lot of Compact Framework development and I would suggest an alternative to use the Smart Device Unit Testing.

Refactor your code so that your UI is just a View. (Ie it does nothing but call other classes.)  Then put your non-UI classes under Unit test.  (Just normal unit tests.)

Visual Studio will give you a warning when you first create the normal unit test project, but after that it is smooth sailing.

There are 3 reasons for doing this:

1. Speed.  It takes a lot less time to run your unit tests this way.
2. Ease.  As you have seen, getting the smart device unit testing up and working takes a bit
3. Compatibility. By doing this you get access to tools like Rhino Mocks.

Now the drawback:

1. You are not "really" testing your code in the NETCF environment.

While the drawback is significant, unit tests are not a substitute for "real" testing which would quickly catch any issues that would be missed by that drawback.